# How to open a Slack channel URL in Slack app

Tags: slack

I can open a Slack channel in browser.
The URL looks like this:

https://myCompany.slack.com/messages/CDPNQL/

The problem is that I can't see that channel inside my Slack app.
I can access it only in browser.

How can I add it to my Slack app?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Do you maybe want to open a channel in your Slack desktop app instead of the browser?

Answer (score -2):

You need to add the workspace in your Slack app.
The path in Slack for Linux is: `Window -> Sing in Another Workspace`